# Как выбрать и использовать профайлер?

Tags: c++, linux, профилирование

Здравствуйте! Как выбрать и использовать `C++` профайлер для `Linux`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное попробовать разные. Например, запросить в гугле

```
c++ profiler linux
```

и выбрать какие понравятся для тестирования. Затем пользоваться тем, что более удобен.

Стандартно в Linux можно использовать [gprof](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gprof) (который с большой долей вероятности уже присутствует в вашей системе).

В простейшем варианте компилируете свою программу

```
 g++ -g -pg myprog.cpp
```

получая ./a.out, запускаете его (вместе с результатами образуется файл ./gmon.out), запускаете `gprof` и анализируйте результат.

(только помните, что простой девиз -- `"Think"` -- это лучшее средство для отладки и анализа программ)